# How exactly can I show the items in the Recyclerview list?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

On some screens, when the list is opened, it is half shown, but I want to show it fully, briefly, I do not want to show the half items that are out of the list. Is there a way to do this ?

Example :

[image]

I haven't tried anything about it because I couldn't find the right source on the internet. I guess it's a problem that occurs in very specific situations.

Comment: How can you show the whole list if it doesn't fit on the screen? I don't understand what you're asking to do.

Comment: I don't want to show half the list, not the whole list, so I don't want to show the unfinished list item when the user comes across it. @Tenfour04

Comment: Can You post your recyclerview code?

Comment: So you want items to be invisible until they are fully on the screen, and then they pop in?